# Use table() inside dataframes stored in a list to create new dataframes

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
library lubridate

eventtime<-c("2020-02-07 22:06:00","2020-02-07 22:00:00","2020-02-07 21:46:00")
eventvalue<-c("home","work",'exit')
geof<-data.frame(eventtime,eventvalue)
```

Then I use a list to store them and assign the list elements to different data.frames using:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

list1 <- geof %>%
  split(.$eventvalue) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(EventHour = hour(eventtime)) %>%
  split(.$eventvalue)

for (i in names(list1)) setNames(assign(i, data.frame(list1[[i]])), names(list1))
```

I would like then to use `table()` based on EventHour for each dataframe to create new dataframes with the frequency of each `EventHour` and then rename those columns

```
#table the events by count of hours
tablegeh<-data.frame(table(home$EventHour))

colnames(tablegeh)<-c("Hour","Frequency")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply`:

```
lapply(list1, function(x) table(x$EventHour))
#> $exit
#> 21 
#>  1 
#>
#> $home
#> 22 
#>  1 
#>
#> $work
#> 22 
#>  1
```

Obviously, you only have a single entry in each data frame, so the "tables" don't look much like tables!

Comment: how can I save those new dataframes and rename their columns as well?yes they re just examples

Comment: @firmo23 you can choose whichever names you want if you do, for example, `lapply(list1, function(x) setNames(as.data.frame(table(x$EventHour)), c("Hour", "n")))`. If you want to save them, you can save the whole list as an RDS, or convert them all into one big data frame using `do.call(rbind, list1)`, or save each one to csv using `mapply(function(x) write.csv(x, y), list1, c("exit.csv", "home.csv", "work.csv"))`

Comment: thank you but I do not mean to save them in a file but as separated dataframes for later use

Comment: @firmo23 if you do `list2 <- lapply(list1, function(x) table(x$EventHour))` then you can access each one by e.g. `list2$home`, which gives you the whole `home` data frame. If you like you can store a copy outside the list with `home <- list2$home`